# I need some help with the Load function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have links w/ class="ajax" that I want to retrieve the element with id="test" from the file "data.html" in the same directory, and put that content into the id="content" div on my page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.ajax").click(function(event){
    $("#content").load("/data #test");
    });
});
</script>
<a class="ajax" href="#">Text</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

and externally, but in the same directory, I have data.html:

```
<div id="test">Will this show up?</div>
```

On the clicking of the anchor, Safari reports "page loading interupted", and no change occurs.

I definitely have JQuery called in the header. Can I get some help with this function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `/data` but the file is `/data.html`, assuming you're in the root. :)

I just tested what you have with this change and it works fine for me. I also recommend you get a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) so you can easily see what your AJAX requests are doing.

Comment: Great help, thanks. It's so hard to not work in an environment where I can just lean over in my chair and say "Hey, what' wrong with this?". Stack Overflow is so useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.html",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (answer) {
        $("main_content").html($(answer).find("div#content_id").html());
    }
});
```

I hope it will help you.